# Using Web API endpoints but would like to hide sensitive information like passwords from query string before logging

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api2, query-string

I have a Web API application with REST endpoints and some of the endpoints take pin numbers and passwords on the query string.  I also have a generic logging statement in the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Generic logging stuff here
}
```

My logging ends up putting this sensitive information into the log file.  Now my ideal solution would to be able to decorate specific endpoints with an attribute like **[Sensitive]** that I could flag for in the `Application_EndRequest()` routine and run a regular expression or something to remove the sensitive data.  That would look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Sensitive]  //This attribute "Sensitive" is what I'd like to be able to place and check for later
public string GetUserToken([FromUri] string login, [FromUri] string password)
{
     // stuff
}
```

However, from the `Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` function, it doesn't seem the parameters or class instance members have what I need to be able to see what attributes the calling endpoint has.

Comment: My immediate reaction is don't pass sensitive information to an endpoint via the URL.

Comment: Why not?  It's over https, so its not inherently insecure. There is just an issue when logging the endpoint.  In any case this is not a situation where the endpoint can be changed as there are deployed clients that are expecting this interface.